# Converting heterogenous vector to array in C++

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a solution for converting a three dimensional vector into a three dimensional array.

I could create a loop to copy the array content inside a three dimensional vector, but there is a catch: The vector is constituted of very heterogeneous 2D vectors.

Here is the argument in the constructor of my frame:

```c++
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double> > >& Mdonnees
```

The first size is not a problem, the second size is the number of lines catched in a file and the last size is always 2 (number of data for every line)

```
[quantity of datasets][quantity of lines][quantity of data/line]
```

For using the freechart function Addserie (in a XY plot), I need an array of 2D arrays so I can add the series previously got with a simple loop.
I need to be able to get in every elements of the first dimension of this array an array like that:

```c++
double data1[][2] = {
    { 10, 20, },
    { 13, 16, },
    { 7, 30, },
    { 15, 34, },
    { 25, 4, },
};
```

Thank you

Comment: What does `wx` have to do with any thing here?  It doesn't seem relevant at all, please remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, three nested loops should indeed work - one to loop through each `vector<vector<double> >`, and two inside that loop to build the two-dimensional arrays that you need using the `vector<double>`s and `double`s.

EDIT: To clarify, you don't need a three-dimensional array. Instead, a `vector<double[][] >` would probably better suit your purposes, as each of the two-dimensional arrays can then be a different size.

Comment: Yes, it seem correct, but how to declare a three dimentional array where I can add every 2D etherogenous array I extract? I suppose it's possible with pointer array but I don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: Oh nice. Wise and simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, but for my understanding, this should work:

```
int n_rows = 0; // the number of rows in the array
for (unsigned i = 0; i < Mdonnees.size(); ++i)
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < Mdonnees[i].size(); ++j)
    ++n_rows; // since the 2D vectors have different size, compute the number of rows this way
double **data1 = new double*[n_rows];
for (int i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i)
  data1[i] = new double[2]; // allocate memory for the array
int row = 0;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < Mdonnees.size(); ++i)
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < Mdonnees[i].size(); ++j)
    for (unsigned k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
      data1[row++][k] = Mdonnees[i][j][k]; // convert data
// work with array
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i)
  delete[] data1[i];
delete[] data1; // free the memory
```